# How to enable sending email when clicked on email id?

Tags: php, android, email, onclicklistener

I am developing an android app for an University. I have an email id mentioned in certain activity of my app. I want the user to send a mail when clicked on this email id as we do using HTML using a mailto function. I searched all the possible way but could not get a solution relative to my requirement. Here is a small snippet of my code.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
android:text="admissions@abc.edu" />
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this. Please anyone guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:autoLink="email"` to your `TextView`

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView6"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
  android:autoLink="email"
  android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
  android:text="admissions@abc.edu" />
```

Comment: Great:) Thanks a lot Apoorv. U made my day.

Comment: Yes surely will do. Have a great day.